# waitForExpectationsWithTimeout crashes

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I am trying to test an asynchronous request with XCTest and so using expectationWithDescription:.
Yet when waitForExpectationsWithTimeout is called it immediately crashes without even waiting for the timeout.
I even tried putting the fulfill operation soon after just to exclude a timeout issue, but it di no change things; this is my function:

```
func testTrafficRefresh(){
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("refreshed")
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10, handler:nil)
    traffic.trafficRefresh {[weak self] () -> Void in
        let coming=inArrivoHDDetailViewController.sharedDetailController().activeTransit
        let buses=self!.traffic.arrivingBuses
        let count=buses.count
        XCTAssert(count==0 && coming==0, "No buses and active transit")
        XCTAssert(count>0 && coming==1, "Arriving buses and inactive transit")
        expectation.fulfill()   
    }
}
```

The same behavior happens in other functions. If I take away the waitForExpectationsWithTimeout operation and keep the expectationWithDescription operation, it crashes at the end of the function. In both case the crash repot is the following:

> ```
> libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
> 0x10723227c <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax
> 0x107232281 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
> 0x107232284 <+8>:  syscall 
> 0x107232286 <+10>: jae    0x107232290               ; <+20>
> 0x107232288 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
> 0x10723228b <+15>: jmp    0x10722dc53               ; cerror_nocancel
> 0x107232290 <+20>: retq   
> 0x107232291 <+21>: nop    
> 0x107232292 <+22>: nop    
> 0x107232293 <+23>: nop
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to provide implementation for the handler. As per docs `handler` parameter is not optional in `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` markup:

```
func waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(timeout: NSTimeInterval, handler handlerOrNil: XCWaitCompletionHandler!)
```

Therefore you can try to provide explicity unwrapped handler(even empty one will do the job):

```
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10) { error in
        //XCTAssertNil(error, "") this is optional
    }
```

Also you could try to follow [this](http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/?utm_content=bufferf0885&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin.com&utm_campaign=buffer) post and see whether you get more appropriate crash log.

Comment: Yes, I did it actually putting waitForExpectationsWithTimeout at the end of the function as hinted in the WWDC2014 I just viewed and for some reason all test resolve correctly. The crash seems to be connected to some test failures, but I was not able to understand when this happens. Anyway my experience is that when there is no failed test there is also no strange crash. I did not need to provide an handler though. I am submitting an answer with the working code.

Answer (score 2):

I watched the specific talk in WWDC14 and came out with the following implementation:

```
 func testTrafficRefresh(){
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("refreshed")
    traffic.trafficRefresh {[weak self] () -> Void in
        let coming=inArrivoHDDetailViewController.sharedDetailController().activeTransit
        let buses=self!.traffic.arrivingBuses
        let count=buses.count
        XCTAssert(((count == 0 && coming==1)||(count>0 && coming==1)), "Transit status \(coming) not corresponding to arriving buses \(count)")
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(20, handler:nil)
}
```

it is very similar to the original one but for the position of the waitForExpectationsWithTimeout command, that seems to be crucial.